# Update JSON file placeholder with regex from ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Assuming the following JSON:

```json
{
   "A":{
      "A_KEY":"%PLACEHOLDER_1%",
      "B_KEY":"%PLACEHOLDER_2%"
   }
}
```

And, the following values.yaml:

```yaml
placeholders:
  PLACEHOLDER_1: Hello
  PLACEHOLDER_2: World
```

I would like to load this JSON using Configmap into my pod. But, replace the placeholders with the values under `values.yaml` **automatically based on the key**.
Thought about writing a simple regex which will search for the words between two `%` and use this word with `.Values.placeholders.$1`.

So far, I managed to replace single value using:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  config.json: |-
    {{- regexReplaceAll "%PLACEHOLDER_1%" (  .Files.Get "config.json") .Values.placeholders.PLACEHOLDER_1 | nindent 4 }}
```

The final goal is to replace both PLACEHOLDER_1 and PLACEHOLDER_2 by single regex.

desired JSON:

```json
{
   "A":{
      "A_KEY":"Hello",
      "B_KEY":"World"
   }
}
```

Any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  config.json: |-
    {{- $file := .Files.Get "config.json" }}
    {{- range $k, $v := .Values.placeholders }}
      {{- $file = regexReplaceAll (printf "%%%s%%" $k) $file  $v }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- print $file | nindent 4 }}
```

I load a config file content into a `$file` variable and then iterate over all placeholers.keys from values.yaml file and replace them one by one, saving the output back to the same variable. At the end, `$file` variable has all fields substituted so I just print it.

Comment: I have been stuck on it for ages, thanks!

Comment: Do you have by any chance an example of load multiple JSON's from a folder and replacing the placeholders? pretty much the same answer but with range over a folder. thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure how is that supposed to work. I'd need to to show me some examples with expected outputs etc. But its better if you create a new question for it.

Comment: Correct, i'll work with the solution you provided for now. thanks again